# Delete duplicate strings in string array

Tags: java, arrays, string-matching

I am making a program based on string processing in Java in which I need to remove duplicate strings from a string array.  In this program, the size of all strings are same.

The 'array' which is a string array contains a number of strings in which two strings resemble each other.  So using the below code the duplicate string must get removed but it is not removed.

How to remove the duplicate strings?

I am using the following code.

```
    for(int s=0;s<array.length-1;s++)
    {
        for(int m=0;m<array.length;m++)
        {
                for(int n=0;n<array[m].length();n++)
                {   
                    if(array[s].charAt(n)==array[m].charAt(n))
                    {
                      continue;
                    }
                    else 
                break;
        } 
        if(n==array[m].length())
        {
            ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, array[s]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you have got now?

Comment: Why don't you use a structure better suited for removing duplicate, like a HashSet for example, instead of arrays?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This will work

```
array = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array)).toArray(new String[0]);
```

or just use a `HashSet` instead of an array.

Comment: What is the purpose of `new String[0]`?

Comment: @Stevoisiak heres a link explaining the use of new String[0] https://stackoverflow.com/a/65902425/16034206

Answer (score 8):

Proposed solution does not keep the order of the elements. If you use Java 8 or higher and want to maintain the order you can use streams as follows:

```
array = Arrays.stream(array).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
```

Full example: https://www.javacodeexamples.com/java-string-array-remove-duplicates-example/849

Answer (score 2):

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
Collections.addAll(set, array);
```

or start with

```
for(int s=0;s<array.length-1;s++)
{
    for(int m=s + 1;m<array.length;m++)
    {

                if(array[s] != null && array[s].equals(array[m]))
                {
                  // array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, array[s]); --m;??
                  array[m] = null; // Mark for deletion later on
                }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless this is `[homework]` I would use a Set

```
String[] array =
Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Stringarray {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        String[] name = {"aim","rajesh","raju","aim"};

    Set<String> myset  = new HashSet<String>();
    Collections.addAll(myset,name);

       System.out.println(myset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set data structure will do automatically  the job for.
Most likely option for you will be `HashSet`, if you care about the order of elements look at `TreeSet`

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList(array);
Set<String> unique = new HashSet<>(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Why don't you use `String.equals()` for comparison instead of iterating through the characters in the strings manually?
- Your logic is actually flawed: for `array[s]` == `"12345"` and `array[m]` == `"123"` it would claim that they are equal
- moreover, in your inner loop `for(int m=0;m<array.length;m++)` `m` will also become equal to `s` at some point, so you will compare a string to itself

These notes assume that you need to implement the removal logic with your own code, not being allowed to use the class library. If this is not the case, as others noted, using a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you remove the most inner loop with in favor of `String.equals(String)`?

In first iteration you are comparing array[0] with array[0] which are equal, and it would be removed. Then you will compare the original array[1] with all other elements in array, and if they are equal, you are removing array[1] (not the other one).

There are some problems, if there are some duplicate Strings, you are removing the first one, which will reduce the size of the array without reducing `r` so, some of the Strings in the array are skipped.

I would use a data structure which forces uniqueness, such as a Set.

What will happen if you have 3 equal Strings in your array, I'm not sure what will happen.

I believe you would encounter some `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s.

Answer (score 0):

I think the if condition at the end should be
if(n==(array[m].length()-1))

Having said that, you seem to be trying to implement what String.equals() method does in your inner most loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
     String[] arr = {"w10","w20","w10","w30","w20","w40","w50","w50"};
     List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
     int cnt= 0;
       //List<String> arrList = Arrays.asList(arr);
       List<String> lenList = new ArrayList<String>();
          for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
           if(arr[i].equals(arr[j])){
             cnt+=1;
           }                
        }
        if(cnt<1){
          arrList.add(arr[i]);
        }
          cnt=0;
        }

for(int k=0;k<arrList.size();k++){
            System.out.println("Array without Duplicates: "+arrList.get(k));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] months={"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Jan","Mar","May","May"};
for(int i=0;i<months.length;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<months.length;j++){
        if(months[i].equalsIgnoreCase(months[j])){
            if(!al.contains(months[i])){
                al.add(months[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
Sring[] myStringArray = {"hello", "hello", "moto"};
String[] filteredArray = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(myStringArray))
                         .toArray(new String[0]);

System.out.println("filteredArray Size: " + filteredArray.length);
System.out.println("filteredArray[0] = " + filteredArray[0]);
System.out.println("filteredArray[1] = " + filteredArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<String> sortHandleArrayList(String... arrayInput) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : arrayInput) {
        if (!list.contains(string)) {
            list.add(string);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicate String from String[] without using Collection

```
    public static void removeDuplicate(String[] str, int size){
            for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++){
                if(str[i]!=null){
                    for(int j=i+1; j<size-1; j++){
                        if(str[i].equals(str[j])){
                            str[j]=null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
                if(str[i]==null)
                   continue;
                System.out.println(str[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

Duplicate integer remove : this is the perfect answer 
/// Haris  ///

```
public static void duplicateRemove(int[] arr) {
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] < arr[j]) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    int count;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length;) {
        count = 1;
        for (int i = j + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                count++;
            } else
                break;

        }
        System.out.println(arr[j] + " is :  " + count);
        j += count;
    }

}
```

Comment: The question is regarding removing duplicate STRINGS not integers