# What's the use of new String[0] in toArray(new String[0]);

Tags: java, android

Why do we need the argument `new String[0]` inside `toArray`?

```
saved = getSharedPreferences("searches", MODE_PRIVATE);
String[] mystring = saved.getAll().keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

So that you get back a `String[]`. The one without any argument gives back to you an `Object[]`.

See you have 2 versions of this method:

- [`Object[] toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29)
- [`<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T[]%29)

By passing `String[]` array, you are using the generic version.

---

A better way to pass the `String[]` array would be to initialize it with the size of the `Set`, and not with size 0, so that there is not need to create a new array in the method:

```
Set<String> set = saved.getAll().keySet();
String[] mystring = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
```

Comment: I personally have always found found this requirement kind of odd, it would make more sense to me to pass the `Class.class`

Comment: @StormeHawke That would involve reflection, which carries a higher overhead than creating an array.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense.  Still, it's not very intuitive this way.  Seems to me they could have hidden this complexity somehow

Comment: Ideally you should initialize the array to the correct size, so it can be filled in. Otherwise, a new array is created.

Comment: why some people use it to iterate over a hashmap? @RohitJain

Comment: @SamBarnum 
Does anybody know, why Intellij IDEA (2018.1, 2019.2) [offers](https://pastenow.ru/74XPE) exactly an **empty** array?

Comment: @DanBrandt I believe with Java 8 it's actually more efficient to use the empty array.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29444594/14467

Comment: what is the 0 represent for? will 0 be automatically replaced with set.size() event if I pass in 0?

Answer (score 9):

To add some more details to the accepted answer, some IDEs (IntelliJ here) give helpful comments and explanations to why they rise a warning on an active inspection when using `new String[c.size()]` versus using `new String[0]` as an argument of `toArray` method:

> There are two styles to convert a collection to an array: either using
> a pre-sized array (like `c.toArray(new String[c.size()]`)) or using an
> empty array (like `c.toArray(new String[0])`. In older Java versions
> using pre-sized array was recommended, as the reflection call which is
> necessary to create an array of proper size was quite slow. However
> since late updates of OpenJDK 6 this call was intrinsified, making the
> performance of the empty array version the same and sometimes even
> better, compared to the pre-sized version. Also passing pre-sized
> array is dangerous for a concurrent or synchronized collection as a
> data race is possible between the size and toArray call which may
> result in extra nulls at the end of the array, if the collection was
> concurrently shrunk during the operation. This inspection allows to
> follow the uniform style: either using an empty array (which is
> recommended in modern Java) or using a pre-sized array (which might be
> faster in older Java versions or non-HotSpot based JVMs).

Hope it helps to further understand why things are done a certain way.

Comment: NetBeans 18 just warned about `toArray(new Predicate[]{})` and suggested `toArray(Predicate[]::New)` instead.  It would be interesting to know why.

Answer (score 5):

It's to provide a type for the return and prevent any compile-time ambiguity.

the signiture for that method call is: `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`

wheras the empty parameter one is `Object[] toArray()`