# How to find unique values in a list of strings in java

Tags: java

I want to get a new array of strings without duplicate values from the original array of strings. For example if the original array is {a b b b c d, a a b b c, a b c c }, my new string should not contain duplicates. I have not been able to figure it out at all as all the solutions in different threads talk about single string arrays and not multiple ones like this. I don't know if I have to use the .split function and add to a hashset and then add it back to a new list that I created.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected result? An array ["abcd", "abc", "abc"]? Something else?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/10366856/8283737

Comment: Do you have an array of arrays of strings where the strings are a, b or c, like [["a", "b", "b"], ["a", "a", "b", "b"]]? You say "my new string should not contain duplicates", do you mean array? Would your example of  {a b b b c d, a a b b c, a b c c } leave an array of three arrays, ["a","b","c","d"], ["a","b","c"] and ["a","b","c"]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete duplicate strings in string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366856/delete-duplicate-strings-in-string-array)

Comment: You are mixing a lot of terminology so it is not clear what you are asking.  Do you have a List or a array?  Are you trying to create a new collection or affect the existing collection?  Are you removing duplicate letters from each String or are you removing duplicate Strings from the collection? Your example adds nothing because it does not include the expected result of that data set.

Comment: @JollyJoker yes that is the expected output i want.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

As explained in the first line in the docs:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

```java
String[] array = { "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "a" ,"b", "c", "c" };
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

The result is `[a, b, c, d]`.

Or in one line using Java8:

```java
array = Arrays.stream(array).distinct().toArray(String[]::new);
```

You can check [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-array-to-set-and-set-to-array) as a reference.